# Sharepoint custom xsl does not render image from column url

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

I have a little problem. I created a custom xsl file where I render the fields from my custom list. I have an column with a picture hyperlink. In the list the picture is shown, but I could not render it on my custom xsl file. I searched on the internet but couldn't find an answer for it. I am not using itemstyle.xsl.

Here is the code

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a sample of the source XML (or at least the content of `@Image`) as well as a sample of the generated output for your image (which would give clues as to why it is not rendering.

Comment: Also, post the XSLT **code**, not screenshots. You can redact your CSS URL and substitute whatever. You are far more likely to get some assistance if you make it easier for people to help you.